# Javascript comparison operators order

Tags: javascript, comparison, operators

I saw a couple of times code like `"expected" === variable` instead of `variable === "expected"`.

Why is that? Is it *performance* or *readability* related? I personally find it more confusing and I always wondered why would someone write the string first, and then the variable in a comparison operation.

Comment: _Yoda conditions_. Use them you will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason is to protect against a single equals typo causing assignment. Commonly known as Yoda Conditions (thanks Paul S in the comments).

E.g:

```
var i = 1;
if(i = 2)  //no error, but unexpected behavior 
if(2 = i) //error - invalid left hand side assignment.
```

The `if(i=2)` option would cause unexpected behaviour because it would assign 2 to i and also enter the if statement which could be a subtle bug that is hard to track down compared with receiving an error. This approach is even more useful for a compiled language such as C++ where the compiler will raise an error so you know about it during compile time. C# and Java compilers don't allow conditionals to be an assignment, so the ordering is of less value there.

Comment: If only I new how to search for it, or about Yoda Conditions, great answer.